# How do I add unique constraint for 2 columns without deleting the existing duplicated records?

Tags: mysql

I had this table, col1 col2 col3, col1 is the primary key, now I want to add unique constraint  for col2 and col3, i used alter table add constraint, but it seems there were already duplicated records in the table, so I have to delete them to make it work, BUT, if I need to keep all the existing records, how can i make sure that the newly added records are unique constraint in col2 and col3?

Comment: What good are the constraints if the table still contains invalid data. Fix the data, then add the constraints.

Comment: But it's not unique if you keep the existing records. It means every single query that uses the older records won't do what you want. So, why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: You can fix the duplicates with an update (adding "-col1" after col2 and col3 to make them unique.) With an update on selected duplicates you only have to do this on the rows that are duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to leave the current duplicates but you want to insure you don’t add any new duplicates, right?  Personally I would follow the comments above, but I understand if that doesn’t meet your business needs.

Unfortunately a constraint does not meet your needs as you describe them.  You may want to control the duplicate logic in the software inserting the data, not at the table level.
For instance the following will only add the row if val3 does not already exist in the table.  Make sense?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES (val1, val2, val3, val4) WHERE NOT col3 = val3;
```

OR you can fire an INSTEAD OF trigger.  SQL has a special temporary ‘inserted’ table that you can compare against right before your values go in.  So you say, “Insert these values, BUT WAIT! Only insert them if the rows in the temp ‘inserted’ table don’t match the existing rows in MyTable."

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_duplicates_in_MyTable ON MyTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT M.val3
      FROM MyTable M, inserted I
      WHERE M.val3 = I.val3))
   INSERT INTO MyTable
      SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4
      FROM inserted
END
```

OR you can handle the logic at the table level with an AFTER INSERT trigger, but it’s a little wonky.  You could delete the existing duplicates, in some cases.  Something like this;

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_duplicates_MyTable
AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM MyTable 
   WHERE val3 NOT IN (SELECT MIN(val3) 
                             FROM MyTable 
                             WHERE val1 = new. val1)
   AND val1 = new. val1;
END;
```

Let me know if you have any questions or if this does not meet your business needs.

EDIT: @Rik is correct, these are INSERT triggers so they will NOT work for updates, allowing anyone's code to change a value to a duplicate.  Try UPDATE triggers.  You can noodle around with these changing INSERT to UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the temporary table, unfortunately mysql doesn't have a default 'inserted' table, so I use NEW.F1 F2 F3 instead, but still got syntax error

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER no_duplicates_in_version
BEFORE INSERT ON version
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT version.product_id
      FROM version
      WHERE version.produc_id = NEW.product_id))
   INSERT INTO version (id, name, product_id)
      VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.product_id)
END

Comment: I don't know if you can change your insert like that. This should work (if Mysql is correct version) `CREATE TRIGGER no_duplicates_in_version
BEFORE INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE num_rows INTEGER;  
  DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_rows
  FROM test WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id;
  IF (num_rows>0) THEN
    set msg = concat('Duplicate Error: Trying to insert a duplicate: ', cast(new.product_id as char));
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
  end if;
END//` It throws an exception if duplicate detected. (note the changed // terminator)

Comment: B.T.W. this only works on insert. Nothing prevents you from changing product_id into a duplicate !! Second: you can insert code in a comment with the backticks around the code. (not pretty but it works)

Comment: I've spent a whole day on this trigger thing, then I did some research and followed the first method BClaydon told me, added some codes in my PHP code, It worked!Thank you all again, I learned a lot from you guys! And thanks Rik, I'll try that and tell you the results.

Comment: @Rik - Great idea to raise a human readable error. And thanks for pointing out that these only work on INSERTs and not UPDATEs.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd go along with the other's comments. You should really fix the data, then add the constraints.

However, just for the sake of it, a possible solution could be to use the MERGE engine. Basically you'd keep the data you have now in one table and create an almost identical second table. Only difference, the index is unique this time.

See this example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
   a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   message CHAR(20),
   key whatever (message)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE t2 (
   a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   message CHAR(20),
   unique key whatever (message)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO t1 (message) VALUES ('Testing'),('Testing'),('t1');
INSERT INTO t2 (message) VALUES ('Testing'),('table'),('t2');

CREATE TABLE total (
   a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   message CHAR(20), INDEX(a))
   ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(t1,t2) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;

select * from total; 
/*Here you can see, that there are duplicate values*/

insert into total (message) values ('Testing');
/*but this results in a duplicate key error*/

insert into total (message) values ('it work\'s');
/*whereas this doesn't*/
```

Read more about the MERGE engine [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html).